# stripe.subscriptions.retrieve not working - Stripe Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, stripe-payment-intent, stripe-payments-js

When trying to retrieve a Stripe subscription I get

> Logged Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'retrieve')

Here's how I'm trying to retrieve a subscription:

```
const stripeSubscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(
    subId
  );

console.log(stripeSubscription);
```

Reference: [Retrieve subscription Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/retrieve?lang=node)

I was using version:
"stripe": "^8.222.0"

Then upgraded to version
"stripe": "^10.10.0"

Still not working. What am I missing or doing anything wrong?

Any help or guide is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The syntax that you're showing there looks right. Could you share a larger code snippet that has all necessary lines to reproduce the behavior that you're experiencing?

Comment: It's straightforward, and I use Stripe in other parts with no issue. @toby

```
const stripe = require("stripe");


const getSubscriptionDetails = async () => {
  const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(
   'id xxxx'
  );

  return subscription;
};

if (stripe) {
  const stripeSubscription = getSubscriptionDetails();

  console.log(stripeSubscription);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not fully initializing the client as it looks like a secret key is not being provided to it.

Where you currently have:
`const stripe = require("stripe")`

can you try updating that line to include your secret key as shown in line 1 of the snippet within the documentation that you referenced, so that it looks like this, but with your actual secret key:
`const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_XXX")`